# (Sum of multiples of $3$ between $1$ and $100$) $-$ (Sum of multiples of $3$ between $5$ and $95$)

Tags: arithmetic-progressions

$m$ is the sum of all multiples of $3$ between $1$ and $100$. $n$ is the sum of all multiples of $3$ between $5$ and $95$. what is $m-n$?

Comment: Any thoughts?  What numbers are counted by $m$ but not by $n$?

Comment: $198$, by inspection.  How was I able to see it right away, and how can you formulate that into a proper solution?

Comment: No math (or very little)  All logic.  The multiples of $3$ between $5$ and $95$ are being subtracted for the multiples of $3$ between $1$ and $100$.  That leaves just the multiples of $3$ that *aren't* between $5$ and $95$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $m$ is the sum of all multiples of $3$ between $1$ and $100$, then that is the sum of all multiples between $1$ and $5$, plus all multiples between $5$ and $95$ and all multiples between $95$ and $100$.

Don't read what's below

> All multiples between $1$ and $5$ is $3$.  The sum of all multiples between $5$ and $95$ is $n$.  And the multples between $95$ and $100$ are $96$ and $99$.

Really.  Do NOT read what's below!

> So $m = 3 + n  +96 +99 = n + 198$.

Surely, you don't need to read what's below.

> ANd $m -n = (n+198)-n = 198$

And under *NO* circumstances read what is hidden below!!!

> ***QUIT IT!!!!!!***